# npm Cannot find fstream module - Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10

For anything I try install with npm it returns the same error: Cannot find fstream module. The funny thing is that 'fstream' is into my NodeJS folder (`C:/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/npm/node_modules`)

I've tried to reinstalling, uninstalling and reinstalling, installing others nodejs versions, restarting the system and nothing!

Here is a log example trying to install firebase tools

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Checho\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'firebase-tools' ]
2 info using npm@5.3.0
3 info using node@v8.5.0
4 verbose npm-session 1f5a9f5441b96d8f
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module 'fstream'
7 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
7 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
7 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
7 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
7 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Checho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\entry.js:14:15)
7 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
7 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
7 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
7 verbose stack     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
7 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
7 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
7 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
7 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Checho\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\entry-writer.js:5:13)
7 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
7 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
7 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
8 verbose cwd C:\Users\Checho\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs
9 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
10 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Checho\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "firebase-tools"
11 verbose node v8.5.0
12 verbose npm  v5.3.0
13 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
14 error Cannot find module 'fstream'
15 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!
Just copying the `C:\Program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules` directory into `C:\Users\{ my-user }\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` and replacing all their files.

Is there where the globally files are located. But in last update of npm something wrong must have happened.